# django-import-export import multiple files

Tags: django-import-export

I am using django-import-export library to import several excel books. However, I have over 1,000 books that need to be imported into the db. Is there a way to select a folder to upload instead of selecting and uploading each individual file? I've worked through the tutorial found here: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration
but I was unable to find the answer to my question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Posting mainly for future viewers. Currently, `django_import_export` imports only the active/first sheet of a single excel workbook. However, the code is easy enough to modify and alleviate this problem. In [forms.py](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/forms.py#L9), there is `ImportForm` which is the one used while importing from admin. Simply change the `import_file` field to something like this:

```
import_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': 
                             True}),
                             label=_('File to import')
                             )
```

This form is used in [admin.py](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/admin.py#L284) to process the file data. Change the linked line to something like:

```
import_files = request.FILES.getlist('import_file')
for import_file in import_files:
    ...
```

Now all that's left is to modify the import procedure in [base_formats.py](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/formats/base_formats.py) for [XLS](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/formats/base_formats.py#L166) and [XLSX](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/formats/base_formats.py#L188) formats. The changes will be nearly same for both, I will outline the `XLS` one here.

Instead of taking the first sheet, run a `for` loop over the sheets and append the data to the dataset.

```
dataset = tablib.Dataset()
first_sheet = True    # If you keep all correct headers only in first sheet
for sheet in xls_book.sheets():
    if first_sheet:
        dataset.headers = sheet.row_values(0)
    first_sheet = False
    for i in moves.range(1, sheet.nrows):
        dataset.append(sheet.row_values(i))
return dataset
```

For XLSX, the loop will run on `xlsx_book.worksheets`. Rest is similar to `xls`.

This will allow you to select multiple excel workbooks and import all the sheets for a workbook. I know the ideal solution would be to import a `zip` file to create all the data using a single `bulk_create`, but this serves well for now.